Can't write on .md5 file when externalizing tikz
The reason I deleted my earlier post only to repost it is because I was exhausted when I wrote the first copy and it was riddled with mistakes, even after a revision. I thought it would be more sensible to come back and try again when I was prepared to write in detail.

I want to externalize the tikzpictures in a local document of mine. The test.tex document is in a folder called foo, and inside foo is a folder called bar. I run pdflatex --shell-escape --enable-write18 "C:\Users\twill\OneDrive\Desktop\foo\test.tex" in the powershell. When I do so, a test.log file is not formed. The console output is below.

This author was dissatisfies with their solution: Error using tikz externalize: can't write md5 file, and other similar questions I've seen were from around 9 years ago.
MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=bar/]
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(1);
\end{tikzpicture}

some more text
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle(2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

EXPECTED OUTPUT

UPDATED CONSOL OUTPUT
PS C:\Users\twill> pdflatex --shell-escape --enable-write18 "C:\Users\twill\foo\test.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(c:/Users/twill/foo/test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.co
de.tex)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryex
ternal.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzex
ternalshared.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! I can't write on file `bar/test-figure0.md5'.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.9 \end{tikzpicture}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-Z to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name:

LOG WHEN RUN WITHOUT EXTERNAL
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.7.3)  6 SEP 2024 15:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count194
\c@section=\count195
\c@subsection=\count196
\c@subsubsection=\count197
\c@paragraph=\count198
\c@subparagraph=\count199
\c@figure=\count266
\c@table=\count267
\abovecaptionskip=\skip49
\belowcaptionskip=\skip50
\bibindent=\dimen141
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen142
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen143
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box52
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2024/05/23 v1.4g Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2023/12/02 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 106.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2024/04/13 v1.2c Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen144
\Gin@req@width=\dimen145
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.co
de.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen146
\pgf@y=\dimen147
\pgf@xa=\dimen148
\pgf@ya=\dimen149
\pgf@xb=\dimen150
\pgf@yb=\dimen151
\pgf@xc=\dimen152
\pgf@yc=\dimen153
\pgf@xd=\dimen154
\pgf@yd=\dimen155
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count268
\c@pgf@countb=\count269
\c@pgf@countc=\count270
\c@pgf@countd=\count271
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count272
 (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count273
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count274
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen156
\pgfmath@count=\count275
\pgfmath@box=\box53
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count276
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen157
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen158
\pgf@picminy=\dimen159
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen160
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen162
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen163
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen164
\pgf@xx=\dimen165
\pgf@xy=\dimen166
\pgf@yx=\dimen167
\pgf@yy=\dimen168
\pgf@zx=\dimen169
\pgf@zy=\dimen170
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen171
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen172
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen173
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen174
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box54
\pgf@hbox=\box55
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box56
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count277
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen175
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen177
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen178
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen179
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen180
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count278
\pgf@shadingcount=\count279
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box57
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box58
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen181
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen182
)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen183
\pgffor@skip=\dimen184
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count280
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen185
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen186
\tikz@lasty=\dimen187
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen188
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen190
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen191
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen192
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen193
\tikz@figbox=\box59
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box60
\tikz@tempbox=\box61
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box62
\tikztreelevel=\count281
\tikznumberofchildren=\count282
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count283
\tikz@fig@count=\count284

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count285
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count286
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count287
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count288

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-05-08 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count289
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count290
\scratchdimen=\dimen194
\scratchbox=\box64
\nofMPsegments=\count291
\nofMParguments=\count292
\everyMPshowfont=\toks30
\MPscratchCnt=\count293
\MPscratchDim=\dimen195
\MPnumerator=\count294
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count295
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks31
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))

[1

{c:/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-05-27>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11720 strings out of 473584
 245479 string characters out of 5732364
 1926908 words of memory out of 5000000
 34450 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,5n,107p,401b,348s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 13307 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


move it some place other than onedrive. it won't work there.

The issue is persisting. I'll update the question with the new console output

Ah, my apologies. I was getting the .md5 errors previously, and added that based on my search history. In hindsight, I should have double checked my sources. Is my impression correct that this is a non-latex issue? If so, maybe you might still know a way to approach this?

does C:\Users\twill\foo\bar\  exist?

yes, and it contains a file (in this case a .txt), as is recommended in the overleaf article on it: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_lot_of_tikz%2C_matlab2tikz_or_pgfplots_figures%2C_so_I%27m_getting_a_compilation_timeout._Can_I_externalise_my_figures%3F

if you drop externalisation temporarily, do you now get test.log?

Yes. I will post it

so what happens if you don't use the prefix option and just let the files be written into the working directory? if you are now getting files written generally, the issue maybe on the latex/external side; when you were not getting even test.log, that had to be something different (like the onedrive thing). however, I'm not the right person if it isn't on the tex/external side because I don't use windows. all I can do is parrot ulrike fischer who said to look into antivirus. (but I'm saying that because she said it, which is a good reason, but I can't tell you what that means to do.)

With the prefix option omitted, it returned an error code of 1 and a log

post the log? externalisation logs are sometimes useless, but sometimes help. incidentally, I just realised you are not actually using overleaf. are you aware there are more recent alternatives to external?

I was not aware of that, though I am now curious how to achieve this. The reason I'm not in overleaf is because I need a longer compile time.

That was a typo :) (I meant to say "now", not "not")

it definitely should be possible to make this work. so by all means satisfy curiosity. but when you decide external is better but not great, you will be curious about the alternatives :-).

Could you tell me what these alternatives are? I'd really like to see if they would be better for the task

the two I'm aware of are memoize, which I'm switching to, and robust-externalize. memoize doesn't need shell escape with tex live because it uses only scripts which have been vetted by karl berry for inclusion on the rather exclusive 'restricted' list. (I think they were probably modified in consultation with karl with precisely this in mind.) I'll see if I can find the post I wrote about it.

Thank you for letting me know! I will definitely investigate both, but it would be convenient not to have to use the command line, so I am inclined towards memoize at this moment. Look forward to seeing the post if you can find it.

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698555/ (pros and cons of memoize example code may need tweaking slightly for current version) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700070/ gives links and brief description of both alternatives, with a reference to the pgf/tikz developers view (which is, basically, that external is unmaintained and the new alternatives are the way to go).

if you post about memoize, please use the tag. the package author isn't here all the time, but does keep an eye on questions about his packages. (at least forest and memoize.)

I'll keep that in mind. Thank you for letting me know

When I do so, a test.log file is not formed  tex always writes a log file in the case shown in the console output (which is not the file you describe in the question text) the log would be written to C:\Users\twill  it is almost always better to cd \Users\twill\foo and then pdflatex test.tex that way the log and any other generated files are generated in the same folder as the document, and any external scripts run in that directory. Giving a full path on the pdflatex command line is possible but complicates all external processing

@DavidCarlisle I had to change the file in the text several times due to a character number limitation (~30000), pardon me for not clarifying that earlier - I suspect that this is why it is different that the file described. Thank you for letting me know about cd!

@Jasper no my comment was unrelated to to the file content. In the text you say you processed C:\Users\twill\OneDrive\Desktop\foo\test.tex but your terminal shows a processing of C:\Users\twill\foo\test.tex which is most likely not the same thing. As your question is about file write permissions paths are more important than any tex content in the file

"inside foo is a floder bar" that is your problem, you are attempting to write to \users\twill\bar not \users\twill\foo\bar

Are you suggesting that when using \tikzexternalize[prefix=<>] that the full path from twill should be specified? I just want to clarify.
